# What float value is associated with each character?

Tags: string, floating

Excuse me in case this questin is silly, but from what I understand, the letter **A** is assigned a smaller float value than the letter **B**, because **B** comes after **A** in the alphabet. What about symbols such as **#** What values are assigned to them? Is there a table somewhere where I can read off the numerical values taken by each symbol?

I tried finding some table of values online

Comment: Look for `ASCII table`.

Comment: You should make sure you're clear on what a "float" is and why it isn't synonymous with "a number".

Answer (score 1):

I think the table you are looking for is an ASCII table, which is a standard conversion from characters to numbers.

For example, "A" is 65, "B" is 66, etc.

A "#" is 35.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII